# sbt test:compile does not compile all tests

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, compilation, sbt

I'm trying to run a single test class *ThisIsTheClassTest.java* in a Java Play project but fails and cannot seem to find the cause.

When I run test:compile the response is plain *[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 5, 2018 9:30:19 PM*

But when using autocomplete to list all available test classes there is one missing.

It seems that it might be the filename itself (for whatever reason) as it all works well if I copy the entire code into another file *ThisIsNotTheFile.java* and run test:Compile. But even if I delete the entire file *ThisIsTheClassTest.java* and add it again it does not work.

If one of the classes did not compile I would not expect the answer *[success]*.

Is there a way to see skipped/failed/ignored compilations or at least additional logging?

Answer (score 1):

The code is probably in the wrong directory.

Comment: Sorry but I fail to see how this would be the problem. All files are located in the same directory and I cannot see how renaming a file would move it?

Comment: You may be experiencing some different problem. I have seen this problem when someone uses an IDE and doesn't know exactly where the files are in the filesystem. For example, I have seen similar errors when:

1. There is a file with the same name in a different directory
2. The file is in the wrong directory, ie `src/main/java` vs `src/test/java`.
3. The class name somehow collides with another existing class name.
4. There is some weird issue with the class compilation cache.

None of these may apply to you. Good luck in any case!